# ¿Qué diferencia una calle de una avenida?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, sustantivos, legislación

Hoy caminando con mi hijo mayor le iba diciendo los nombres de las calles por las que discurríamos. Y el caso es que por la zona donde vivo hay vías muy similares en cuanto a sus características, pero unas eran calles y otras avenidas. (Sí, hay otros tipos pero estos dos son los más comunes.)

El DLE dice que una [avenida](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4Y1msZ9) es:

- Camino que conduce a un pueblo o paraje determinado.
- Vía ancha, a veces con árboles a los lados.

Y una [calle](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6pegX8v) es:

- Vía pública, habitualmente asfaltada o empedrada, entre edificios o solares.
- Camino entre dos hileras de árboles o de otras plantas.

Entiendo que está segunda acepción de calle se refiere a caminos fuera de la ciudad, aunque desde luego hay muchas calles con árboles a los lados y no son avenidas. Luego a juzgar por las definiciones, parece que la diferencia está solo en el ancho de la vía.

Pero como decía, hay calles y avenidas muy similares donde yo vivo, luego ¿cuál es más técnicamente la diferencia? ¿El ancho de la acera además del de la vía? ¿Que la avenida era en sus inicios caminos que conducían hacia la poblacion? ¿Qué le falta al DLE para ser un poquito más preciso?

Comment: Uso particular en  Nueva York.  http://www.guiadenuevayork.com/calles-y-avenidas

Comment: Sospecho que los usos varían mucho. *Avenida* sugiere algo más ancho que *calle* pero eso es todo. Y eso sin contar con otras denominaciones, como *bulevar*, *paseo*, *pasaje*, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Para mí, definitivamente tiene que ver con el ancho de la vía, pero no es lo único. Me explico. Recurriendo al mismo DRAE, etimológicamente, avenida viene de "avenir".

Paradójicamente, una de sus acepciones vuelve a remitir a "avenida", (lo cual es algo frustrante, todo hay que decirlo), pero obviamente se refiere a que miremos la primera acepción:

**Avenida**:

```
1. Creciente impetuosa de un río o arroyo.
```

El uso de avenida como un tipo de calle se debe a la equiparación del flujo de agua (caudal) con el flujo de tráfico.

Avenida es entonces una **vía principal**, por lo general  más ancha de las calles. Esto implicaría

1. El grueso del tráfico circula por la avenida.
2. Se utiliza la avenida para acceder a las calles secundarias.

Así pues, no depende de si tiene árboles ni de muchas otras cosas, aunque sí es propensa a ser ancha y larga, pero lo que de verdad determina si una calle es avenida es si es o no una vía principal de tránsito.

Answer (score 0):

La diferencia está dada por la ***amplitud relativa*** de ambas vías urbanas, para la circulación de peatones (por aceras a los costados) y vehículos o medios de transporte varios (automóviles, motos, bicicletas, camiones, autobuses, etc, por el centro). Así,

> **calle**, es normalmente de un ancho menor y puede o no tener circulación de vehículos en doble sentido

mientras que

> **avenida** es una *vía de mayor ancho e importancia*, generalmente diseñada en el trazado urbano para permitir la circulación de un tráfico más intenso *en ambos sentidos*